# coin change recurrence solution

Tags: dynamic-programming, recurrence

Given a value N, if we want to make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of S = { S1, S2, .. , Sm} valued coins, how many ways can we make the change? The order of coins doesn’t matter.There is additional restriction though: you can only give change with exactly K coins.

For example, for N = 4, k = 2 and S = {1,2,3}, there are two solutions: {2,2},{1,3}. So output should be 2.

Solution:

```
int getways(int coins, int target, int total_coins, int *denomination, int size, int idx)
    {
            int sum = 0, i;
            if (coins > target || total_coins < 0)
                    return 0;
            if (target == coins && total_coins == 0)
                    return 1;
            if (target == coins && total_coins < 0)
                    return 0;
            for (i=idx;i<size;i++) {
                    sum += getways(coins+denomination[i], target, total_coins-1, denomination, size, i);
            }
            return sum;
    }

    int main()
    {
            int target = 49;
            int total_coins = 15;
            int denomination[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
            int size = sizeof(denomination)/sizeof(denomination[0]);
            printf("%d\n", getways(0, target, total_coins, denomination, size, 0));
    }
```

Above is recursive solution. However i need help with my dynamic programming solution:

Let `dp[i][j][k]` represent sum up to `i` with `j` elements and `k` coins.

So,

```
dp[i][j][k] = dp[i][j-1][k] + dp[i-a[j]][j][k-1]
```

Is my recurrence relation right?

Comment: It should be precisely the same as the ordinary coin change problem, but with one digit for number of coins left. I'm surprised you have a 3D dp matrix. Ordinary coin chaing is typically 1D, and with an extra coin, you should end up with a 2D matrix. I guess what I'm trying to ask is what does *"j elements"* mean?

Comment: @aioobe: j is the index of the array.

Comment: Yes, but what does it represent. `k` represents the number of coins, what does `j` represent?

Comment: @aioobe: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change look at this.

Comment: Right. But just because you have 3 nested loops doesn't necessarily mean that you need a 3D dp.

Comment: @aioobe: I am wondering where is 3 nested loops in my solution. I can just see 3 dimensions.

Comment: Yes, and I'm telling you that you don't need 3 dimensions. Only two: You need to keep track of *current sum*, and *current number of coins left*.

Comment: @aioobe: I understand coin sum with 2 dimensions as shown in the algorithmist site. So I wanted to extend the solution to add this  new restriction.

Comment: I can't immediately see why they have 2 dimensions. They are not creating a *sum* in each cell though, so it may be the case that they are keeping track of the numbers more explicitly. I wouldn't recommend starting with that solution and try to extend it. Have a look at [this](http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F07/dynamic.pdf) for instance, or [this](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/jaa/CS7800.12F/Information/Handouts/dyn_prog.pdf).

Comment: did you have a look at the above links? I think they describe a solution that is easier to work with and extend.

Comment: @aioobe: I understand completely the 1d solution for the minimum number of coins and your solution for the same. I just wanted to know the recurrence relation which i had got in my mind when i first saw this question. So wanted to know if my first thoughts were right/wrong?

Comment: I'll read it through again to see if I can give you a response on that... Give me a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80829/discussion-between-aioobe-and-newbie-old).

Comment: Your recurrence is correct! You can drop the middle j because see when you reach any DP[i][k] it will have the value of DP[i][j-1][k] and the second part is a smaller j th sub problem i.e. it will be calculated before the present problem that means DP[i-a[j]][k] has been computed for the j th element! Hence one can drop the middle j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your recurrence relation:

> Let `dp[i][j][k]` represent sum up to `i` with `j` elements and `k` coins.

I think you're on the right track, but I suggest simply dropping the middle dimension `[j]`, and use `dp[sum][coinsLeft]` as follows:

```
dp[0][0] = 1  // coins: 0, desired sum: 0  =>  1 solution
dp[i][0] = 0  // coins: 0, desired sum: i  =>  0 solutions

dp[sum][coinsLeft] = dp[sum - S1][coinsLeft-1]
                   + dp[sum - S2][coinsLeft-1]
                   + ...
                   + dp[sum - SM][coinsLeft-1]
```

The answer is then to be found at `dp[N][K]` (= number of ways to add *K* coins to get *N* cents)

Here's some sample code (I advice you to not look until you've tried to solve it yourself. It's a good exercise):

> ```
> public static int combinations(int numCoinsToUse, int targetSum, int[] denom) {
>     // dp[numCoins][sum]  ==  ways to get sum using numCoins
>     int[][] dp = new int[numCoinsToUse+1][targetSum];
>
>      // Any sum (except 0) is impossible with 0 coins
>      for (int sum = 0; sum < targetSum; sum++) {
>          dp[0][sum] = sum == 0 ? 1 : 0;
>      }
>
>      // Gradually increase number of coins
>      for (int c = 1; c <= numCoinsToUse; c++)
>          for (int sum = 0; sum < targetSum; sum++)
>              for (int d : denom)
>                  if (sum >= d)
>                      dp[c][sum] += dp[c-1][sum - d];
>      return dp[numCoinsToUse][targetSum-1];
>  }
> ```

Using your example input:

`combinations(2, 4, new int[] {1, 2, 3} )  // gives 2`

Comment: Your recurrence is correct! You can drop the middle j because see when you reach any DP[i][k] it will have the value of DP[i][j-1][k] and the second part is a smaller j th sub problem i.e. it will be calculated before the present problem that means DP[i-a[j]][k] has been computed for the j th element!   Hence one can drop the middle j

Comment: This is my understanding too.